# Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account message in stackoverflow

Tags: support, questions, new-users

Why am I getting the following message in stackoverflow ?

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: @or100, you should ask this sort of question at http://meta.stackoverflow.com but there are many existing questions on the topic, such as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account). Basically you have been banned for posting poor-quality questions.

Answer (score 2):

When an account has been posting low quality content, this warning will appear.

Questions from the account have been downvoted by the community due to their overall poor quality, lack of effort or variants thereof.

To rectify this you can try and edit your earlier questions to be more clear, include more and relevant information or less inflammatory.